# Missing SQL Tools in VS 2013

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm beginner in programming, and trying to make a project with Entity Framework. I'm using MS VS 2013 Express and SQL Server 2012 Express, and a tutorial from Microsoft.

When I try to "Generate Database from Model" I expect to see a hightlighted code and special tools to work with it:

[image]

But I have no any of them in my VS 2013.

What am doing wrong, and what should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution for my problem on my own. I deleted and reinstalled VS 2013, and now it contains SQL Server features. Maybe the problem was in a proper order of installation of VS and SQL Server. So, firstly we install SQL Server and then - Visual Studio.

Also, before it I tried to use SQL Server 2014 with Visual Studio 2013 and it raised more errors.

I hope somebody will find it useful.